Asymptotic behavior of sum
Let $A\subset N$ be a set of zero density and let $a_1$ be its smallest
element. Also, let $L:[a_1, +\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb R_+$ be an increasing function which is continuous and differentiable on $[a_1, +\infty)$. Assume moreover that $L'(x) =O(1)$. Prove that the following two statements are equivalent:
(a) $$\sum_{a\le x,a\in A}L(a)=(1+o(1))x$$
(b) $$A(x)=(1+o(1))\int_{a_1}^x{\mathrm dt\over L(t)}$$
where $A(x)=\sum\limits_{a\le x,a\in A}1$ and density of $A$ is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{A(x)\over x}$.
This is problem 1.11 from Jean-Marie De Koninck & Florian Luca's Analytic Number Theory. I've figured out the $\text{(a)}\Rightarrow\text{(b)}$ part, yet when trying $\text{(b)}\Rightarrow\text{(a)}$ I encountered some problems:
By Abel summation formula,
$$\sum_{a\le x,a\in A}L(a)=\sum_{a\le x}L(a)\chi_A(a)=A(x)L(x)-\int_{a_1}^x A(x)L'(t)\mathrm dt$$
Substituing $A(x)=(1+\varepsilon(x))\int_{a_1}^x{\mathrm dt\over L(t)}$ in, and with some integral by parts,
$$\sum_{a\le x,a\in A}L(a)=(1+o(1))x+\varepsilon(x)L(x)\int_{a_1}^x{\mathrm dt\over L(t)}-\int_{a_1}^x\varepsilon(t)L'(t)\left(\int_{a_1}^t{\mathrm du\over L(u)}\right)\mathrm dt$$
Yet unlike the first part, $L(x)\int_{a_1}^x{\mathrm dt\over L(t)}$ cannot be bounded by $Kx$ easily. However I haven't used the condition that $A$ is of density $0$; the only information I can infer is that $\int_{a_1}^x{\mathrm dt\over L(t)}=o(x)$, which I don't know how to use.
